# MATLAB parallel computing setup

Tags: optimization, matlab, parallel-processing

I have a quad core computer; and I use the parallel computing toolbox.
I set different number for the "worker" number in the parallel computing setting, for example 2,4,8..............
However, no matter what I set, the AVERAGE cpu usage by MATLAB is exactly 25% of total CPU usage; and None of the cores run at 100% (All are around 10%-30%). I am using MATLAB to run optimization problem, so I really want my quad core computer using all its power to do the computing. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a number of workers (up to 4 on a quad-core) is not enough. You also need to use a command like `parfor` to signal to Matlab what part of the calculation should be distributed among the workers.

I am curious about what kind of optimization you're running. Normally, optimization problems are very difficult to parallelize, since the result of every iteration depends on the previous one. However, if you want to e.g. try and fit multiple models to the data, or if you have to fit multiple data sets, then you can easily run these in parallel as opposed to sequentially.

Note that having many cores may not be sufficient in terms of resources - if performing the optimization on one worker uses k GB of RAM, performing it on n workers requires at least n*k GB of RAM.

Comment: I am using the global optimization toolbox. And I have set the global optimization toolbox using parallel computing. Basically, the global optimization toolbox will use many initial start points; each starting point can be considered one new calculation. That's why it can take advantage from parallel computing. However, it does NOT work in my computer. Please help

Comment: @Marco: Just to be sure we're on the same page: You did create four workers by calling `matlabpool open 4` (and you have checked that you indeed see 4 Matlab sessions in your task manager). Then, you initialized your multistart problem as `ms = MultiStart('UseParallel','always');`. Correct?

Comment: @Marco: As to testing: Did you compare the time it took between running the problem with one worker only with running the problem with four workers (i.e. `tic,run(ms,problem,200);toc` for both cases)? Do you see any difference? If yes, then it works on your computer, but the problem might be too trivial to make the processors sweat. Also, if there is hyperthreading on your processors, they'll show 50% use even if they actually use 100% of resources.

Comment: I did "matlabpool open 4", also I did the MultiStart('UseParallel','always').

Comment: I should try the tic,run(ms,problem,200);toc. I will report after I test my computer. For the hyperthreading, I don't think I have it because I was looking at the real time graph of all four cores performance, (All are around 10%-30%). And the average is really like 25% and this number match with the task manager report.

Comment: I am sorry that I did not make as a correct answer 6 years ago :)

Comment: @Marco: no problem :)